# Sql to java JDBC database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a problem with searching a particular contact using part of a name. I know how it would look like in SQL but I cant implement it using Java.

```
if (rs.getString(nameTable  LIKE '%name1%';)
```

[image]

Comment: you should delegate that logic to database .. and just check resultset.

Comment: This would compile `if (rs.getString("nameTable  LIKE '%name1%';"))`

Comment: how can i delegate it to database? is it considered as example? (Statement stmt
                = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE)

Comment: Can you share the table structure?

Comment: You need to add this condition to the query you want to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding the `LIKE` clause to your SQL query instead of handling it in java code:

```
  try(PreparedStatment ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * " +
         " FROM Contact WHERE contactName like ?")) {
    ps.setString(1, "%name1%");
    try(ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
      while(rs.next()) {
        //process your data
      }
    }
  } catch(Exception e) {
    //deal with it
  }
```